# Why does the "local maxima" module in SAGA GIS put so many "maxima" points on lakes and plains?

Tags: qgis, point, saga, topography

SAGA GIS puts too many maxima points on plains and lakes. Why does it happen? Is there a way to avoid this? It's not really a big problem (the value is correct) except for the size of the SHP files in certain areas, and it does not look very nice. The Global Mapper for example ignores the "plain" areas. Can this be fixed?

Below is the effect of local maxima module through Sextante in QGIS:

[image: Effect of local maxima module through Sextante in QGIS]

The purpose is to provide a nice and optimal SHP terrain model for WindPro, with inflection points, and it does not like large files.

Comment: Could you please supply more information on your data.  What is the source?  How did you generate this data?  Can you provide an example of where the "plain" areas are ignored?

Comment: The source for the above is Polish CODGiK http://www.codgik.gov.pl/index.php/darmowe-dane/nmt-100.html, but it does not matter. When you try to make maxima on any raster source, SRTM 4.1 or ASTER GDEM, the result is the same on plain areas (multiple points). The data was generated using the SAGA GIS with the Shapes-Grid -> Local minima and maxima. It was done in Sextante toolbox but the result is the same in SAGA (as it's the same algorithm). Unfortunately I cannot give the example in Global Mapper, I just saw it on my colleague's computer. It just ignores the large flat areas (such as lakes).

Comment: I suppose that the DEM has some noise and lakes are not totally flat. Then a minimal difference in height will make a local maxima. If SAGA does not have a tolerance setting for filtering out the very little maxima values then you can perhaps make the lakes flat with raster calculator "set heigth=100.00 when 99.90<heighth<100.10".

Comment: I checked. It's totally flat. It's the same with other data source.